# Appending to a list in python throws an error

Tags: python, list

I am fairly new to Python and what I am trying to do is the following:

1. Read a file
2. Add elements to a dictionary for each line
3. If the key already exists, then get the values for they key into a list and append the new value to the list.
4. Update the dictionary with the new list of values

Here is my code:

```
jobChangeMap=dict() # Maps the changed job name. Format will be      jobset,originaljob,jobNumber:jobset,changedjob,jobnumber
jobValues = []

if(not jobsetName in jobsetJobMap.keys()):
    logger.debug("{0} not found as a key. Adding key and value pair".format(jobsetName))
    jobsetJobMap.update({jobsetName:jobName+","+jobNumber})
    logger.debug(jobsetJobMap)
else:
    jobValues = []
    jobValues[:]=[]
    logger.debug("{0} already found as a key. Getting list of values for key".format(jobsetName))
    jobValues=jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]
    logger.debug("Number of values for {0} is {1}".format(jobsetName,jobValues.count))
    logger.debug(jobsetJobMap)
    if(not jobName in jobValues):
        myJobName=jobName+","+jobNumber
        logger.debug("Size before adding: {0}".format(len(jobValues)))
        jobValues.append(myJobName)
```

This is the line that throws the following error:

```
File "D:\Git-Python\MountSophie-Conversion\jmoConversion\JMOExtract.py", line 163, in createJobMap
    jobValues.append(myJobName)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why is Python complaining about jobValues being a str object even though I explicitly defined it as type list?

Comment: Subsequently you have `jobValues=jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]`, so the earlier `jobValues = []` is irrelevant.

Comment: You've changed the type of `jobValues` to `str` through this statement - `jobValues=jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]`.

Comment: @khelwood - I need to get the values into a list. I thought that was the code to get the list of values for a key. Is that not so?

Comment: `jobValues.append(jobsetJobMap[jobsetName])` will add the string to your existing list. `jobValues = [jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]]` will make a new list and containing the string and assign it to your variable. `jobValues=jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]` will **replace** whatever is currently in your variable (a list) with the stuff on the right of the `=` (a string).

Comment: Apparently `jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]` is a string, not a list

Comment: Python variables are not typed, it is a dynamic language.

Comment: @JohnSquarry No, in a dictionary a key is associated to one value, not a list of values. The value can be a list though.

Comment: @JohnSquarry Please don't deface your question by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The values of `jobsetJobMap` appear to be strings according to this line:

```
jobsetJobMap.update({jobsetName:jobName+","+jobNumber})
```

That overwrites the entry `jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]` with a new string, `jobName+","+jobNumber` which you later retrieve and set as the value of `jobValues` in this line:

```
jobValues = jobsetJobMap[jobsetName]
```

That overwrites the previous `list` value of `jobValues` with a string, and strings have no `.append` method—hence your error message.

Inferring your intention from your variable names, I think you want to do something like:

```
# (earlier initialization)
import collections
jobsetJobMap = collections.defaultdict(list)
# ...
# (later update):
    jobsetJobMap[jobsetName].append( jobName + "," + jobNumber )
```

That appends a job descriptor to a list (implicitly creating the list, if necessary) that is associated with the key `jobsetName` in the `jobsetJobMap` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you've been having. @jez answer explains it perfectly.

You are obviously new to python, and you've been living in the Java/C# world for too long. JK.

Why I am saying this?

Well first of all, the variables naming convention you are using (CamelCase) is so [Java/C#]-style. You should prefer snack_case on python. Refer to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

You are right about using python for this sort of program. Because python is so powerful when it comes to this kind of problems. However you are not using python powers to their best. This shouldn't take so many code lines.

Keep your data structures homogeneous. In `jobsetJobMap` you are storing either a string or an array. You might want to save them all as arrays even if they contain only one element. Heterogeneous data result on more code and more code equal more bugs.

I would suggest something more like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

lines = ['name1,1', 'name2,2', 'name1,3', 'name2,1', 'name3,1', 'name3,1']

jobs_map = {}

for line in lines:
    [name, number] = line.split(',', 1)
    if name in jobs_map:
        jobs_map[name].append("%s,%s" % (name, number))
    else:
        jobs_map[name] = ["%s,%s" % (name, number)]
```

Comment: yes you are right.I have been in the c# world for far too long...my problem, which I didn't explain very well, is this: the data structure should be a dictionary of the format, key: ListofValues. If when I read through the file, I find that the key exists, then I need to append to the existing list of values. if the key exists and the value also exists in the list of values, then I am making the new value unique and then I need to add it back to the list of values for the key. Unfortunately I am very new to Python as you noticed. not sure how to solve it in python :-(

Comment: Also to the people that have downvoted, you are probably experts at this. I am not

Comment: I think that your code still complicated though. All those if/else statements aren't right. Can you post all your code even the part in which you read from the file. Because I am not able to completely understand  the purpose of your code.

Comment: is there an email address you want me to send this to? or just here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to work through this. it may not be the smartest code but its my attempt at a solution in Python

```
if(not jobsetName in jobsetJobMap.keys()):
                    jobValues = []
                    myNewJobName=jobName+","+jobNumber
                    jobValues.append(myNewJobName)
                    logger.debug("{0} not found as a key. Adding key and value pair".format(jobsetName))
                    jobsetJobMap.update({jobsetName:jobValues})
                    logger.debug(jobsetJobMap)
                else:
                    jobValues = []

                    logger.debug("{0} already found as a key. Getting list of values for key".format(jobsetName))
                    jobValues=jobsetJobMap.get(jobsetName) # Get list of values associated with the key.


                    logger.debug(jobsetJobMap)
                    if(not jobName in jobValues):
                        myJobName=jobName+","+jobNumber
                        logger.debug("Size before adding: {0}".format(len(jobValues)))
                        jobValues.append(myJobName)
                        jobsetJobMap.update({jobsetName:jobValues})

                    else:
                        jobCount=jobValues.count(jobName)
                        logger.debug("Job {0} already exists in the list. Adding a unique name")
                        newJobName=jobName+".M"+jobCount+","+jobNumber
                        logger.debug("{0} changed to {1}".format(jobName,newJobName))
                        jobChangeMap.update({jobsetName+","+jobName+","+jobNumber:jobsetName+","+newJobName+","+jobNumber})
                        jobValues.append(newJobName)
                        jobsetJobMap.update({jobsetName: jobValues})
```

Comment: Thanks to @jez and Abdelhakim Akodadi for pointing me in the right direction!. Let me know again if this is too complicated to achieve what its doing.